# How to delete multiple row from DB table by laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to delete all comments from comments table.I did that by doing this but this is not the laravel way. Anyone answer the correct steps please .

```
$comments = Comment::where('post_id',$id)->get();
    if(count($comments)>1)
    {
        $comment_id= [];
        foreach ($comments as $i)
        {
            $comment_id[] = $i->id;
        }
        for($i=0;$i<count($comments);$i++)
        {
            Comment::find($comment_id[$i])->delete();
        }
    }
    elseif (count($comments)==1)
    {
        $comments->delete();
    }
```

Comment: Please scepicify the name of the fields. and the 'Something by Laravel in destroy method'

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since each Eloquent model serves as a query builder, try this, all in one line:

```
Comment::where('post_id',$id)->delete();
```

Tested in tinker, works as expected, returns count of deleted rows.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#deletes

Answer (score 3):

```
DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $ids_to_delete)->delete();
```

or

```
$org-products()->whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your code and how does it answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following approach:

```
public function deleteAll(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->ids;
    Comment::whereIn('id',explode(",",$ids))->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect only ids from your command like below and destroy by model.

```
$yourRaws = YourModel::where('name', 'Enver')->get();
...
YourModel::destroy($yourRaws->pluck('id')->toArray());
```

Enjoy Your Coding !